# NLTK WordNetLemmatizer processes "US" as "u"

Tags: python, nltk, lemmatization

If you feed the word `"US"` (United States), after preprocessing (which becomes `"us"`, i.e in lower case) into the `WordNetLemmatizer` from package `nltk.stem`, it is translated to `"u"`. For example:

```
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
lmtzr = WordNetLemmatizer()
word = "US".lower()  #  "US" becomes "us"
lemma = lmtzr.lemmatize(word)
print(lemma)  # prints "u"
```

I have even tried to lemmatize the word using POS tagging, which results in an `'NNP'` (NN=Noun and P=Proper, i.e proper noun) according to the `pos_tag()` function from package `nltk`. But `'NNP'` is a `wordnet.NOUN`, which is the default behavior of the lemmatizer when it processes a word. Therefore, `lmtzr.lemmatize(word)` and `lmtz.lemmatize(word, wordnet.NOUN)` is the same (where `wordnet` is imported from package `nltk.stem.wordnet`).

Any ideas about how to tackle this problem, apart from the clumsy way of explicitly excluding the processing of the word `"us"` in a text from the lemmatizer using an `if` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the source code of WordNetLemmatizer

```
def lemmatize(self, word, pos=NOUN):
    lemmas = wordnet._morphy(word, pos)
    return min(lemmas, key=len) if lemmas else word
```

`wordnet._morphy` returns `['us', 'u']`

`min(lemmas, key=len)` returns the shortest word which is `u`

`wordnet._morphy` uses a rule for nouns which replaces ending `"s"` with `""`.

Here is the list of substitutions

`[('s', ''),
 ('ses', 's'),
 ('ves', 'f'),
 ('xes', 'x'),
 ('zes', 'z'),
 ('ches', 'ch'),
 ('shes', 'sh'),
 ('men', 'man'),
 ('ies', 'y')]`

I don't see a very clean way out.

1) You may write a special rule for excluding all-upper-case words.

2) Or you may add a line `us us`

to the file `nltk_data/corpora/wordnet/noun.exc`

3) You may write your own function to select the longest word (which might be wrong for other words)

```
from nltk.corpus.reader.wordnet import NOUN
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
def lemmatize(word, pos=NOUN):
    lemmas = wordnet._morphy(word, pos)
    return max(lemmas, key=len) if lemmas else word
```